# Работа с sqlite: ошибка OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Начал работать с sqlite и вместо вывода на консоль данных таблицы sqlite выводится такая ошибка

```
    02-11 15:26:42.568 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 0
02-11 15:26:42.578 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 34359738371
02-11 15:26:42.580 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 5242945
02-11 15:26:42.582 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 5242944
02-11 15:26:42.596 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 240518168576
02-11 15:26:42.599 22352-22418/com.example.rrota.myapplication E/OpenGLRenderer: allen debug liyu Key: 68724719680
02
```

код MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
EditText etName, etEmail;

DBHelper dbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
    btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

    // создаем объект для создания и управления версиями БД
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // создаем объект для данных
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    // получаем данные из полей ввода
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

    // подключаемся к БД
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
            // подготовим данные для вставки в виде пар: наименование столбца - значение

            cv.put("name", name);
            cv.put("email", email);
            // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
            long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRead:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");
            // делаем запрос всех данных из таблицы mytable, получаем Cursor
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            // ставим позицию курсора на первую строку выборки
            // если в выборке нет строк, вернется false
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
                int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
                int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

                do {
                    // получаем значения по номерам столбцов и пишем все в лог
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                            "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) +
                                    ", name = " + c.getString(nameColIndex) +
                                    ", email = " + c.getString(emailColIndex));
                    // переход на следующую строку
                    // а если следующей нет (текущая - последняя), то false - выходим из цикла
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
            c.close();
            break;
        case R.id.btnClear:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Clear mytable: ---");
            // удаляем все записи
            int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + clearCount);
            break;
    }
    // закрываем подключение к БД
    dbHelper.close();
}



class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // конструктор суперкласса
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
        // создаем таблицу с полями
        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "name text,"
                + "email text" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

}

код main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Read">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @pavlofff исправил

Comment: Для начала исправьте строку на: `db.execSQL("create table mytable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, email text);");` - вам не нужно разрывать строку, так как у вас только текстовые составляющие и динамически ничего не добавляется, это только путает. Потом колонка с ID в андроид обязательно должна иметь имя `_id` и никакое другое, для корректной работы. После того, как исправите, удалите ваше приложение с тестирующего устройства, чтобы БД была создано заново, иначе изменения не будут применены.

Comment: Так же вы привели не тот лог о ошибке, это просто служебная информация при работе ОС. Ошибка должна включать какие то Exception, смотреть ее надо на вкладке Logcat в самом конце обычно, после того, как приложение упало. Пример [стектрейса ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782871/177345)(первый блок).

Comment: у вас лог пишет в debug, соответственно чтобы увидеть сообщения в Logcat нужно в Logcat выбрать отображение ошибок Debug.